# tint color is changing color of image in navigation bar swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode8

I put image instead of bar button item in navigation bar, and tint color is changing image color. I tried to put default tint color to be no color, but xcode is ignoring me. Also tried to make it transparent, but then whole image is transparent. Any ideas what should i do?

Comment: Please share some code with how you've implemented this.  You need to use `imageWithRenderingMode` and `.original`

Comment: that's it. thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'll need to change the rendering mode of your UIImage that you use. UIImage has a method imageWithRenderingMode. You can feed that UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal to get an image that doesn't change based on tint color.

This is from memory and I'm not at a computer to try it out.